# Change CRM 2011 navigation section in Outlook 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

The sections that Outlook shows (Administration, Delivery, Marketing) are ordered in an alphabetical way, whilst they are ordered according to the SiteMap in the online version.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg309259.aspx)  this is the standard behavior:

> Microsoft Outlook presents each navigation area in alphabetical order in a tree view instead of using the order specified in the SiteMap.

But I found also an article with a possible fix:

http://cognettacloud.com/?p=263

Your Office version is 2013 (the article refers to 2010), so you can try to install the latest updates for Office 2013 and check if there are any changes.

Comment: Hi Guido, thanks for your answer. I had already seen the article, our machines are all up to date. I think the only think to do is to wait for some new updates, since opening a ticket for this would be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

you can find multiple Site map editor tools

This is a good one:
http://mscrmtools.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/new-tool-sitemap-editor-for-microsoft.html

it also allows you to modify the outlook display/pane paths